# Altering keras metrics=accuracy

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, keras

I am training a dataset with age in humans and when I run model's compile metrics='accuracy', I don't want it to compute the exact accuracy, but just look for a certain age range and compute the accuracy if it correctly identifies the age range. I am wondering how I could do this. Can I simply edit the compile function?
Thank you

edit: So what I am starting with is https://github.com/yu4u/age-gender-estimation

What I am trying to do is to extract the age, check if it is in a certain range, say 20 - 30 and then determine the accuracy based on if the program is correct in seeing it is 20 - 30 as opposed to checking the accuracy if the program can recognize the exact age. What I thought would be easiest is to add a new metric to the model.compile function seen in lines 71-72 of the train.py file

```
model.compile(optimizer=sgd, loss=["categorical_crossentropy", "categorical_crossentropy"],
          metrics=['accuracy'])
```

A problem I am having is I am not sure how to check the actual age from this file to plug it into the custom metric or even creating a callback

From here, I assume I would have to edit the plot_history.py file to actually plot the accuracy.

If anybody has any ideas, that would be a tremendous help

Thank you again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your own [metric](https://keras.io/metrics/#custom-metrics). However you have to use keras backend functions, because if you use tensorflow for example this will be put in your graph and therefore your metric has to deal with tensors instead of numpy arrays.

Your second option is to write a [custom callback](https://keras.io/callbacks/#create-a-callback) which will print your metric automatically on epochs end. Here you use the model to predict on the validation data set and then simply calculate the metric using numpy arrays as inputs.